# Editing html table cell

Tags: html, html-table

I am using `contenteditable` inside td. It works fine but it also affect the inside content which is hidden by default. For example:

```
<td contenteditable >
  name
  <p contenteditable="false" style="display:none;">12</p>
  <a contenteditable="false"  href="#" >
    <img src="image.png" class="imgspace"/>
  </a>
</td>
```

Here if I am deleting name text it also delete the `<p>` and `<a>` tag which are editable false and also `display:none` by default.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't set `contenteditable` on the `td`. Put a `<p>` tag around name and set it on that.

Comment: it will not give the whole td as editable look and the whole content inside td is parse inside javascript to get the specific value so it is hard to change the tags.

Comment: If it's parsed inside javascript, it should be quite easy to change. I don't think you have any other choice.

Comment: but what about look it will only edit if it contain any text

Comment: I agree which kapa proposed, it doesn't seem there is a way to do as you say. It would be great if you create a pen and post it here, so that we can edit it and show you maintaining the look.